# A consequence of Hasse's reciprocity law of simple algebras

Tags: class-field-theory, local-field, division-algebras

I read somewhere in Godement-Jacquet's book (Zeta functions of simple algebras) the following claim:

Let $D$ be a division algebra over a number field $F$ of dimension $d^2$. For each place $v$ of $F$, write $D_v:=D\otimes_FF_v$. Then $D_v$ is isomorphic to some $M_{m_v}(D_v')$, where $D_v'$ is a division algebra over $F_v$ of dimension $d_v^2$, and $d_v m_v=d$. By general theory in algebraic number theory and simple algebras (all details can be found in Pierce's book Associative Algebras (GTM) or Weil's Basic Number Theory), for all but a finite set of places $d_v=1$, and such $v$ is called "unramified" (otherwise ramified). Now let $a_v:=(-1)^{m_v(d_v-1)}$. Then $a_v=1$ for almost all $v$. Consider the well-defined (essentially finite) product $\prod_va_v$.

Claim: from the Hasse reciprocity law we can deduce that $\prod_va_v=1$. (original writing by the authors: "easy consequence of Hasse's reciprocity")

This made me puzzled. The Hasse reciprocity law is:
$$0\rightarrow Br(K)\rightarrow \oplus_v Br(K_v)\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0.$$
Here the reciprocity law tells us: given $D$, if we consider its "invariants" (local Brauer groups are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ by invariant maps), then the sum of these invariants becomes zero in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. We can be more explicit by writing down the invariant map via the construction of cyclic algebras of uniformizers over unramified extensions.

However, I didn't see how this implies the above formula. The formula claims
$$\sum_{v\in S}d\equiv\sum _{v\in S} m_v (=\sum _{v\in S} d/d_v) \mod{2}.$$
Well, the number $d_v$ is related to the local invariants of $D$, but it simply tells us the denominator of the class of $D_v$ in $Br(F_v)$. How can the reciprocity above imply this formula?

Any hint or suggestions would be welcome. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Would the following work. Let the Hasse invariants be $r_v/d_v+\Bbb{Z}$, $\gcd(r_v,d_v)=1$. For $m_v(d_v-1)$ to be odd, it is necessary that $m_v$ is odd and $d_v$ is even. In other words, the only places that contribute to $\prod_va_v$ are those with $\nu_2(d_v)=\nu_2(d)$ (assuming $2\mid d$ as otherwise there is nothing to prove). Let $\ell=\nu_2(d)$, so $2^\ell$ is the highest power of two dividing $d$. Hasse reciprocity tells us that
$$\sum_v\frac{r_v}{d_v}\in\Bbb{Z}.$$
This implies, by the non-archimedean triangle inequality, that $\nu_2(d_v)=\ell$ for an even number of places. Done.

Comment: For example with $d=4$ the non-trivial Hasse invariants may be A) $1/4$ and $3/4$ or B) $1/4$, $1/2$, $1/4$ (or one of infinitely many other possibilities). The point is that the numerator $4$ must occur an even number of times for the invariants to add up to an integere.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh my god you are right. That's an elegant solution ( even with handy nontrivial example). Thanks a lot!  ( Don't be so modest professor Lahtonen. I just made two stupid typos: the square is lost and almost all $ d_v=1$, not $ d$)  :)

Answer (score 2):

Promoting the comment to an answer.

It turns out that the argument does not require any deeper understanding of class field theory other than the fundamental exact sequence (= Hasse reciprocity, which is surely deep enough!). The rest is about the arithmetic of rational numbers (which may be why the authors called it *easy*).

Let us denote the class of $[D_v]$ in $Br(K_v)\simeq \Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$ by $r_v/d_v+\Bbb{Z}$. This is non-trivial only at a finite set of places $S$. We also know that $\gcd(r_v,d_v)=1$ and
$$\sum_{v\in S}\frac{r_v}{d_v}\in\Bbb{Z}.\qquad(*)$$

The claim $\prod_v a_v=1$ is about how often the integer $m_v(d_v-1)$ can be odd. For $m_v(d_v-1)$ to be odd, both factors need to be odd, so $m_v$ must be odd, and $d_v$ must be even. This never happens unless $d=d_vm_v$ is even, so we can assume that $d=2^\ell d_2$ where $\ell>0$, $2\nmid d_2$.

This means that $m_v$ is odd only when $2^\ell\mid d_v$. For all $v\in S$ we have that $2^\ell r_v/d_v$ is a $2$-adic integer. Furthermore, it is a $2$-adic unit if and only if $2^\ell\mid d_v$. That is, if and only if $m_v(d_v-1)$ is odd. By $(*)$ the sum $\sum_{v\in S}2^\ell r_v/d_v$ is an even integer, so we can conclude that $m_v(d_v-1)$ is an odd integer at an even number of places. This is exactly the claim.